# Wildfly 26 Jakarta EE 9.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly

**Background**
Transforming a Wildfly 17 Java EE project (EAR) to Wildfly 26 and Jakarta EE9.1
Updated all dependencies and changed imports. Also some code changes necessary.

Now i am stuck on resteasy-core-spi-6.0.0.Beta1

When deploying i get this error:

*Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expected static method 'java.lang.Object org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData(java.lang.Class)'*

The Code that calls this method looks like this.

FooClass foo = ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData(FooClass .class);

A look at the SPI Class reveals this.

```
 public static <T> T getContextData(Class<T> type) {
    return getContextDataMap().get(type);
}
```

That looks perfectly fine.

Examining the Wildfly system dir and looking in the module for same jar.(resteasy-core-spi-6.0.0.Beta1,jar)

reveals this

```
<resources>
    <resource-root path="resteasy-core-spi-6.0.0.Beta1.jar"/>
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="java.desktop"/>
    <module name="java.logging"/>
    <module name="java.management"/>
    <module name="java.naming"/>
    <module name="java.xml"/>
    <module name="javax.activation.api"/>
    <module name="javax.annotation.api"/>
    <module name="javax.enterprise.api"/>
    <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
    <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
    <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
    <module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    <module name="org.reactivestreams"/>
</dependencies>
```

I tried to update that to jakarta namespace but no change.

I am at a loss here, do anyone have some ideas?

Comment: Are you using WildFly 26 preview ? Standard WildFly is still JakartaEE 8. Aslo those modules should be aliases to the jakarta one if you are on preview.

Comment: Yes i am using 26.0 Final Java EE9.1 Preview.

Comment: I think you should fill a Jira on Wildfly about this.

Comment: Ok, so i got this sorted.

The key is to NOT have the JAX-RS dep, that is instead now part of Core.

But with a different interface (of course).

Was it well documented? No.


If someone has the same issues, just write and i can elaborate.

Comment: It looks like currently the RESTEasy documentation is not working. However, I think this was documented in the upgrade from RESTEasy 3.x to 4.x. Also you should not include dependencies the container provides.

Comment: No of course not, BUT we need the deps to be able to for isntance use the context.
In version 4 one could use Static methods like this.


  ResteasyProviderFactory.pushContext(Foo.class, foo);

Foo foo = ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData(Foo.class);

However now that is removed.
ResteasyProviderFactory factory = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();

 Map<String, Object> contextProperties = new HashMap<>();

        contextProperties.put("foo",foo);

        factory.setProperties(contextProperties);

And to read

return (Foo)factory.getProperties().get("foo");